# Is it possible in a pandas dataframe to have some multiindexed columns and some singleindexed columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

In pandas I would like to have a dataframe whose some columns have a multi index, some don't.

Visually I would like something like this:

```
  |   c    |    |
  |--------|  d |
  | a  | b |    |
================|
  | 1  | 4 |  0 |
  | 2  | 5 |  1 |
  | 3  | 6 |  2 |
```

In pandas I can do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6], 'd':[0,1,2]})
columns=[('c','a'),('c','b'), 'd']
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
```

and the output would be:

```
   c      d
   a  b NaN
0  1  4   0
1  2  5   1
2  3  6   2
```

However, when accessing the `d` column by `df['d']`, I get as output a Pandas Dataframe, not Pandas series. The problem is clearly that pandas applied multicolumn indexing to every column. So my question is: is there a way to apply column multindexing only to certain columns and leave the others as they are?

In other words, I would like that the result of `df['d']` would be a Series as in a normal dataframe, the result of `df['c']` a pd.DataFrame as in column multindex and the result of `df['c']['a']` a Pandas Series. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the empty string `""` as a placeholder :

```
columns = [
    ("c", "a"),
    ("c", "b"),
    ("d", ""),  # << here 
]
```

Output :

```
type(df["d"])      # pandas.core.series.Series
type(df["c"])      # pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(df["c"]["a"]) # pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: "" or a singleton...

Comment: @Laurent B., I think you need to read (*if not yet*) the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: I read it, and in my answer I said series is `indexes + values` with no header.  `df['d']`gives a series with your approach because you have no header anymore. You have two ways : defining a singleton `('d', np.nan)` or `('d', "")`. In last case you must access series by `df[('d', None)]`or `df[('d', np.nan)]`. Just a different writing style. But the main explanation is the no-header building.

Comment: No, with your approach, `type(df["d"])` gives a DataFrame while mine gives a Series (*which is the expected output*).

Comment: With your approach `df['d']` gives a series, and with mine `df['d', None]` gives a series. I just wanted to insist that the type is influenced by the presence or not of headers. The output in the question contains NaN that's why I used this dataframe.

Comment: I don't understand why you insist but OP clearly said that they want to use `df["d"]` and not `df["d", ***]`.

Comment: Because Pandas do not mixes dataframes and series. The type is turned into a series type because of the lack of headers. A single dataframe column with no headers is seen as a series.

Comment: @Timeless solution is what I was looking for, not only in terms of expected output but it's also simple and elegant. As commented in @LaurentB.'s answer before asking the question I've tried both using `d` and `(d,)` as last column but in terms of output there is no difference. I personally don't like one having to write `df['d', np.nan]` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a singleton `(d,)` like this :

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6], 'd':[0,1,2]})
columns=[('c','a'),('c','b'), ('d',)]
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)

print(df)
```

```
   c      d
   a  b NaN
0  1  4   0
1  2  5   1
2  3  6   2
```

`df['d']` is seen as a dataframe and not a series because of the header. Typically, series have indexes + values.

Like dataframe is a 2-level multiindexes columns you have the sub-level with `NaN` by calling only `df['d']`.

If you want to call the series, you must call `df[('d', np.nan)]`in order that you don't have header anymore.

```py
>>> type(df['d'])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

>>> type(df[('d', np.nan)])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Pandas preserves the MultiIndex structure even when you're accessing a single column.

So, you cannot have a mixed DataFrame where indexing a single column gives you both a Series and a DataFrame based on whether the column is part of a MultiIndex or not.

**Improvement of my answer to Roshach comment**

I prefer improve the answer here on header deletion.

About your output dataframe :

```py
>>> type(df['d'])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Now we will try to delete the header just to see the effect (cf. Timeless answer). I just give the explanation here.

```py
>>> df.columns
MultiIndex([('c', 'a'),
            ('c', 'b'),
            ('d', nan)],
           )

>>> new_columns_list = list(df.columns)
>>> new_columns_list[2]
('d', nan)
>>> new_columns_list[2] = ('d', '')
>>> new_columns_list
[('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('d', '')]
```

Now we convert this `new_columns_list`to multiindex-column :

```py
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_columns_list)

>>> df
   c     d
   a  b   
0  1  4  0
1  2  5  1
2  3  6  2
>>> type(df['d'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

So the deletion of header => `df['d']` is now **converted in** series type

Comment: TBH I have tried using `d` and `(d,)` and did not notice any difference. In fact your printed  dataframe is exactly as the one printed by me.

Comment: If you keep your original designed output, the only way to access series is by a couple like this `df[('d', ...)]`. So you have to delete headers when building the dataframe like Timeless does. It's the presence of header that cause the type to be dataframe.

Comment: How to print the headers of a series? I want to understand better and checj

Comment: In Pandas series has only one header  `s.name` and this is not the column header you should find in a dataframe with this instruction : `df.columns`. If you want when you have a value in columns, it's seen automatically as a dataframe and not a serie (in case of one column)

Comment: `df['d'].columns` gives
`Index([nan], dtype='object')`(There is a value in the list)

Comment: yes, I did'nt say your answer was incorrect, but I just insist on the reason why dataframe is converted into a series : header deletion. It's a conversion operation.

Comment: Between a dataframe with no header and a series, Pandas choose the series type, but at the beginning it was not a series